# How can I convert a Neo4j Node to a Blueprints Vertex?

Tags: java, nosql, neo4j, graph-databases, tinkerpop

I was wondering whether it's possible to get the corresponding Blueprints [**Vertex**](http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/javadocs/blueprints/2.0.0/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/Vertex.html) from a Neo4j [**Node**](http://api.neo4j.org/1.9.6/org/neo4j/graphdb/Node.html) object?

I've been having a look at Neo4j's documentation but I cannot manage to find the way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

Since blueprints is a wrapper over Neo4j, you can go the other way round but not this way. Neo4j knows nothing about the upper layers and thus does not have any reference to blueprints. Maybe you can construct a vertex by inserting the required information via a helper class?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Take a look at [this](http://www.tinkerpop.com/maven2/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/0.3/api/com/tinkerpop/blueprints/pgm/impls/neo4j/Neo4jVertex.html) and [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/neo4j/TWISaqitivo/vcbjZsxKDlAJ)